# How to save an array to file and later read it into an array variable in nodejs/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

in nodejs I want to read some data into an array which has been saved previously to file. The original data is structured in an array. Example:

```
let arr = [
  'id-001': [ '123', '246', '234' ],
  'id-002': [ '789', '235' ],
  ... and so on
];
```

It is saved like this:

```
fs.writeFileSync(dirpath + 'data.txt', arr);
```

This part works fine. The file contains this string:

```
[
  'id-001': [ '123', '246', '234' ],
  'id-002': [ '789', '235' ],
  ... and so on
]
```

Now I thought I could just read the file

```
let data = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8');
```

...that works...

and do something like

```
eval('let arr = ' + data);
```

or

```
let arr = eval(data);
```

or even

```
const vm = require('vm')
let arr = vm.runInNewContext(arr, {data})
```

and some more. Nothing works. It behaves strange, just nothing seems to happen, code after the eval seems not to be executed. No errors.

What may be wrong? Is there a better way?

Comment: The `let arr = …` code at the beginning cannot work because it’s not valid JavaScript syntax.

Comment: @sebastianSimon I guess its rather that `arr.toString()` is not valid JS ...

Comment: @JonasWilms It would be valid, if the syntax errors would be corrected.

Comment: I must be missing something ... Which syntax error?

Comment: @JonasWilms The `:` inside the array.

Comment: Oh right, then the OP is also wrong about the files contents ... The whole question then doesnt make any sense ...

Comment: I just noted that the content of the saved file is not valid syntax. Sorry for that. Should I vote to delete this post?

Comment: Your array is not in correct format use like this 
let arr  = {
  'id-001': [ '123', '246', '234' ],
  'id-002': [ '789', '444' ],
};

Answer (score 5):

You can parse the file content using `JSON.parse` after reading it, that should make it work.

Also, you'll want to persist a `JSON.stringify`ed representation of your data.

Here's a minimum example that shows the whole process:

```
const fs = require('fs');

function write(array, path) {
    fs.writeFileSync(path, JSON.stringify(array));
}

function read(path) {
    const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(path);
    const array = JSON.parse(fileContent);
    return array;
}

write(['a', 'b'], '/my/path/test.txt');
const arr = read('/my/path/test.txt');
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Possible enhancement: save file as `data.json` and use `require('./data.json')` to load it synchronously and efficiently directly into a variable

Comment: Using `require` unfortunately makes node cache the file. You cannot rely on `require` (without emptying its cache) to read files that are regularly changing.

Answer (score 0):

When you write the file you should `stringify` it:

```
fs.writeFileSync(dirpath + 'data.txt', JSON.stringify(arr));
```

Then you simply need to `parse` the string data from the file back to a javascript object

```
let data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8'));
```

Comment: @SebastianSimon True, it should be `stringify`d when saving it. See update

Answer (score 0):

Correct your array 1st and write/read the file

```
const fs = require('fs');

let dir = './data.txt';

let arr  = {'id-001': [ '123', '246', '234' ],
             'id-002': [ '789', '444' ]};

fs.writeFileSync(dir, JSON.stringify(arr));

let data = fs.readFileSync(dir, 'utf8');

console.log(data);
```